# How to match string in a file, but only if the string is in the first field?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, perl

How to match string in a file, but only if the string is in the first field?

```
 param=hbase.tmp.dir
 cat file |   grep $param

 "hbase.local.dir" : "${hbase.tmp.dir}/local",
 "hbase.tmp.dir" : "/var/lib/ambari-metrics-collector/hbase-tmp",
 "hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir" : "${hbase.tmp.dir}/zookeeper",
 "phoenix.spool.directory" : "${hbase.tmp.dir}/phoenix-spool",
```

My expected output is:

```
 "hbase.tmp.dir" : "/var/lib/ambari-metrics-collector/hbase-tmp",
```

Comment: Look, how better is your post now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
awk '($1=="PATTERN")' infile.txt
```

above is correct when your fields are delimited by whitespaces, if not it can mention with `-F` option.

if the PATTERN matching is set within a variable, you should tell it to awk about it with `-v` option.

```
awk -v param="PATTERN" '($1==param)' infile.txt
```

also can get based on if including a PATTERN with `~`.

```
awk -v param="PATTERN" '/$1 ~ param/' infile.txt
```

Or also `grep` can be used as well.

```
grep '^PATTERN.*[^:]'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input data was JSON (it looks suspiciously like it), one could use `jq`:

```
$ jq -r '."hbase.tmp.dir"' file.json
/var/lib/ambari-metrics-collector/hbase-tmp
```

This may have to be modified if there is any sort of complicated data structure, obviously.